# update all rows in table at once by laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have column 'section_order' it's an order section start from 1 to end of the table ,
problem is when i delete one section or more the order is change not go as the same 1,2,3,...
so i want to reorder column 'section_order' by Asc and update it from first row 1,2,3,....
[image]

I try this code but it's wrong

```php
     $last_order = Section::latest('section_order')->get();

     $orders_num=$order_last[0]['section_order'];

     for ($i=1; $i <= $orders_num ; $i++) {
         Section::orderBy('section_order', 'asc')->update([
             'section_order' => $i
         ]);
     }
```

Comment: Let say you have 10 thousands record , those reorder logic will decrease  your site performance . In my opinion getting deleted one record will not damage your order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for my problem 
after delete row update all rows below
there is my code in controller ...

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{

   $ids_delete=$request->section_id;

   if (!empty($ids_delete))
      {
        $ids_delete = explode(",",$request->section_id);

        foreach( $ids_delete as $id_delete)
      {

    $order_id = Section::where('section_id', $id_delete)->first();
    $the_section_order=$order_id->section_order;

    Section::findOrFail($id_delete)->delete();

    Section::where('section_order','>',$the_section_order)
    ->update(['section_order' => DB::Raw('section_order - 1')]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.
When you delete your record please reorder all records like below:

```php
$id = 1; // Id before deleted one
Section::where('id','>',$id)->decrement('section_order');
```

Laravel have default increment() and decrement() method, Which will decrement 'section_order' by one, So no need to use loop and update

Comment: let's say i have 5 rows in my table, when i delete rows number 2,3 so after delete the order will be 1,4,5 so i want to update this to 1,2,3 ... so your code update order to 2,5,6 and i won't that

Comment: @George, You can pass increment value in second parameter like: **Section::where('id','>',$deletedId)->increment('section_order', 2)**;
Section order will increment in all rows in table at once, which has greater id then your deleted one

Comment: @George, Please use last id before deleted id in where clause. As pre your example it will be **where('id','>',1)->increment('section_order', 2)**

Answer (score 0):

To sort and change data with just one SQL query, you can use such a scheme

```
  DB::statement("SET @r=0");
  $query = 'UPDATE `table` SET `column` = @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY `sortable_column` ASC';
  DB::statement($query);
```

Comment: it's give error ..... Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `section_order` ASC' at line 1 (SQL: UPDATE `section` SET `section_order` = @r:= (@r+1) WHERE ORDER BY `section_order` ASC)

Comment: @George  A second you want to update the field on which you are trying to do sort?

Comment: let's say i have 5 rows in my table order like 1,2,3,4,5 and i delete rows number 2,3 so after delete the order will be 1,4,5 so i want to update this to 1,2,3 ... so i want update after delete